# Button stops being clickable when active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the button which the code I show below, it works well when not active, but when I click on it, it changes its color from grey to green as supposed to, but it stops being clickable.

I am no longer able to click on it in order to go back to not active and to its color grey. How can I fix this issue?

```js
$("#TmpFBtn").click(function() {
  if ($("#TmpFBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    $("#TmpFBtn").removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $("#TmpFBtn").addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 14%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #5e6472;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #2a9d8f;
}

.button.active {
  background-color: #2a9d8f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="featuresCB">
  <button class="button pksOnsets" style="width: 100%;" id="TmpFBtn" name="TmpFBtn"> Temporal Features <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I've converted your code to a snippet (and removed the `display:none` so we can see/click the button) - it appears to work correctly.  Click the button it goes green, click it again and it goes back to grey.  Please update the snippet to demonstrate the problem.  See [mcve].

Comment: Reinventing what jQuery already has `$("#TmpFBtn").click(function() { $(this).toggleClass("active"); }`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#TmpFBtn").click(function() {
  if ($("#TmpFBtn").hasClass("active")) {
    $("#TmpFBtn").removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $("#TmpFBtn").addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 14%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #5e6472;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
}
.button.active {
  background-color: #2a9d8f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="featuresCB">
  <button class="button pksOnsets" style="width: 100%;" id="TmpFBtn" name="TmpFBtn"> Temporal Features <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

The problem was mostly with the hover part.As even after 2nd click it remains in the hover state which shows the background green.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, how do I still maintain the hover part tho?

Comment: *"It remains in the hover state"* - this is factually incorrect.  It does keep the same colour as hover but if you move the mouse away it's not "in the hover state" and that can easily be demonstrated by using a different colour for hover/click and moving the mouse over/off the button before/after clicking - which shows that OPs original code was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is working but not visible to you because when you hover on it to click `:hover` is already applied and the background color is applied.
If you inspect and open dev tools you see the active class is being added to it.

So, just remove the :hover state to notice the change.
If you still want to have :hover state, try changing the background color at hover state.

Btw,
A better jQuery for you:

```
$("#TmpFBtn").click(function() { 
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
}
```

It does the same job, but with a lesser number of lines.